# Ajax array value display error

Tags: html, ajax, json

I am basic ajax and using display result(form and custom value(like Json)) ajax. My code:

```
var obj  = {"employees":[
   {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
   {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
   {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]};
var data = $("#userForm").serialize() + "&jsonval=" + obj;                   
 $.ajax({
                    datatype : "json",
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'all.php',
                    data: data,
                    })
```

My Result:

```
Array
(
    [firstname] => frtr
    [lastname] => dfgfdg
    [email] => praneshkanna@gmail.com
    [num] => 2323232323
    [num1] => 34334
    [num2] => 2342
    [num3] => 2432
    [submit] => Submit
    [jsonval] => [object Object]
)
```

Jsonval -display result [object Object].plz help with display result all employees(first name  and Last name).
Thanks for your feature help and correct my fault.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are trying to post JSON Object in post string, so you will need to change Object into string

Change

```
var data = $("#userForm").serialize() + "&jsonval=" + obj;
```

to

```
var data = $("#userForm").serialize() + "&jsonval=" + JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Now you will get JSON content into string on server, so decode `jsonval` field value on server side

Answer (score 1):

Now the obj is *Object* which is converted to *String* with default *toString* which in *Object's* case is "[Object object]". Instead you should convert it to JSON *String* with *JSON.stringify* like this

```
JSON.stringify(obj)
```